# How to optimize this code in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have following 4 methods as before filter in my controller, but these have code similarity

```
before_filter :load_person, except: [:autocomplete]
before_filter :validate_twitter, only: [:recent_tweets, :commonly_following]
before_filter :validate_linkedin, only: [:common_connections]
before_filter :validate_facebook, only: [:mutual_friends]
before_filter :validate_google, only: [:meetings]

def validate_linkedin
  @linkedin_account = current_user.social_account("LinkedIn")
  return render json: { message: "You are not connected to your LinkedIn account" } if @linkedin_account.blank?
  return render json: { message: "No Linkedin url for #{@person.name}" } if @person.linkedin_url.blank?
end 

def validate_twitter
  @twitter_account = current_user.social_account("Twitter")
  return render json: { message: "You are not connected to your Twitter account" } if @twitter_account.blank?
  return render json: { message: "No Twitter username for #{@person.name}" } if @person.twitter_username.blank?
end 

def validate_facebook
  @facebook_account = current_user.social_account("Facebook")
  return render json: { message: "You are not connected to your Facebook account" } if @facebook_account.blank?
end 

def validate_google
  @google_account = current_user.social_account("Google")
  return render json: { message: "You are not connected to your Google account" } if    @google_account.blank?
end 

def load_person
  @person = Person.where(id: params[:id]).first
  return render json: { message: "Cannot find the person with id: #{params[:id]}"} if @person.blank?
end
```

How can I optimize this code?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can dynamically create the four validate methods like this:

```
%w{LinkedIn Twitter Facebook Google}.each do |social_media|
  define_method "validate_#{social_media.downcase}" do
    instance_variable_set("@#{social_media.downcase}_account", current_user.social_account(social_media))
    return render json: { message: "You are not connected to your #{social_media} account" } if instance_variable_get("@#{social_media.downcase}_account").blank?
  end
end
```

Comment: This makes the code DRY, but usually "optimize" implies performance.

Comment: @MarkThomas, well how do you optimize those two lines of code? He's talking about code similarity, so I think he wants his code to be more DRY. Don't you think so?

Comment: Yes I do. My comment was really more for the OP I suppose.

Comment: To cope with the capitalization issue for linkedin, you could pass through the properly capitalized versions in the first place, then downcase them for use in the method/variable names (leaving them as-is in the messages).

Comment: @MarkThomas My intention was DRY to achieve OP

Comment: Depends on what you're optimizing for. If optimizing for DRY, Mischa's code is great (I upvoted it). If optimizing for readability, in my opinion the original code is better.